# How to use EnvironmentObject in UIKit ViewController

Tags: ios, swiftui, uikit, uiviewcontrollerrepresentable

I'm building a SwiftUI app that wraps UIKit `ViewController` through `UIViewControllerRepresentable`. The goal is to display a `UITextView` in my SwiftUI app. The implementation of this is simple, like this:

```
// iOSTextView.swift
import SwiftUI

struct iOSTextView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var document: Document
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some UIViewController {
        let view = iOSTextViewController()
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {

    }
}
```

Notice the `EnvironmentObject` named `UserData`. It's a class that holds some general data that should be shared with every view in my app, including the UITextView ViewController.

```
// UserData.swift
import Foundation

final class UserData: ObservableObject  {
    @Published var someValue = 1
}
```

Below is my `iOSTextViewController` ViewController:

```
// iOSTextViewController.swift
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class iOSTextViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData

    // Create a Text View
    let textView: UITextView = {
        let tv = UITextView()
        return tv
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Place the Text View on the view
        view.addSubview(textView)
        textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        
        // create attributed string
        let string = "This is a string."
        var attributes: [NSMutableAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
            .foregroundColor: UIColor.red,
            .font: UIFont(name: "Courier", size: 12)!
        ]
        let myAttrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string, attributes: attributes)
        textView.attributedText = myAttrString
    }    
}
```

**My questions:**

1. How can I pass `UserData` to my ViewController named `iOSTextViewController`? Should I use a Coordinator? How can I use it to make the `EnvironmentObject` available and synchronized inside my ViewController?
2. In the same way, how can I share my `document` binding, since it's a document-based app?

Comment: Did you get this to work? I have the same issue at the moment.

Comment: I just used `@ObservedObject` instead of `@EnvironmentObject` as a workaround

Answer (score -3):

This can be accomplished in SwiftUI relatively easily, to pass your UserData variable to any object you can make a Published variable in a separate class. Here is an example

```
class UserDataManager: ObservableObject { 

     @Published var userData: UserData = UserData(variable1, variable2...)

}
```

Then in your View struct you can simply do

```
struct TextView: View { 
    
   @ObservedObject var userDataManager = UserDataManager()

   var body : some View {
     
      TextField("Enter your data", text: $userDataManager.userData.name)
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not what I'm asking about, I just edited my question to make it more clear.

Comment: Try using @ObservedObject instead?

Comment: It's a very good idea, but isn't it possible to use @EnvironmentObject ?